# TFS Activity for InvokeProcess (without wait)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I see lots of posts for waiting on the return value of various activities, but in this case, I'd like to kick off an activity and then not wait.  I just want to copy a directory over a (very) slow network, so I'd prefer not to create another activity or use a batch script for this.  Anyone done this?  Is there a clean way?  I could cobble something together, but I'm trying to keep this as vanilla as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that something out of the box is available for you to use. 
One way to proceed is to organize an "Invoke Process" that invokes another service that does the actual copying. So from within Build you advance and let the invoked entity (that is out of scope in terms of TFS build) do the actual activity. This does come with certain deficiencies, the more important being that you won't ever know in your build-logs if this succeeded or failed.
Another option is to use the `Parallel` activity (it's in the Toolbox under "Control Flow" - `System.Activities.Statements.Parallel`). This is not quite like what you need (kick & forget), still it could allow you to do other stuff while your copy happens.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  This is what I'm trying to do - I'd like to just use "start.exe" to kick off an xcopy since I have a string array parameter in the build queue gui box that takes a list of locations to copy the file to.  Unfortunately start does not appear to work from within tfs build.  It appears that start is built into cmd.exe.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything that let me easily do this without creating another activity.  Honestly, creating the activity took me less time than looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Hi Sharon, can you share the build activity? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple custom activity that will create new process:

```
[BuildActivity (HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
public sealed class InvokeProcessAsync : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> FileName { get; set; }

    public InArgument<string> Arguments { get; set; }

    public InArgument<string> WorkingDirectory { get; set; }

    public InArgument<IDictionary<string, string>> EnvironmentVariables { get; set; }



    protected override void Execute (CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.DublicateOperationsLogsToBuildOutput ();

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = context.GetValue (this.FileName),
            Arguments = context.GetValue (this.Arguments),
            WorkingDirectory = context.GetValue (this.WorkingDirectory)
        };

        var env_vars = context.GetValue (this.EnvironmentVariables);
        if (env_vars != null)
        {
            foreach (var v in env_vars)
                psi.EnvironmentVariables.Add (v.Key, v.Value);
        }

        Process.Start (psi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[CopyDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.copydirectory.aspx) activity from the Build.Workflow assembly is what you need.

Comment: CopyDirectory waits.  As I mentioned in my post, the important part of this is to not wait on the copy activity, as it takes a long time.

Comment: OK so I wasn't clear from your question that you wanted something that fires and forgets. CopyDirectory, as any other async activities, does give you a chance to work on something else if used inside a Parallel activity. You mentioned that start.exe doesn't work, what about cmd.exe?